# The direction of the scrollbar of the webpage

Tags: css, jsp, scroll, scrollbar

I run into a problem here. I'm comparing about the scrollbar between two web pages which one does not contain the element encompassed as shown below and the one contains the element encompassed  as shown below. The one that does not contain the code below; the bar will move in the opposite direction when it is scrolled. Whereas, the one that contains the code below corresponds according to the movement of the scroll on the bar. My question is does the part that is encompassed have any relation to the movement of the bar. (scroller-scrollbar-y is this a function of a scrollbar or just a variable). I'm still new to JSP so I'm 
a bit lost here.

[image: Part of the code from jsp]

**Below is the CSS**

```
compass-scroll-accordion {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
     -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
     -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
     transform: translateZ(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems these two classes are customized CSS style. You need to check the detail for the style definition

Comment: I've added the CSS part above.